# Deploy NodeJS applications on azure service fabric cluster

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-service-fabric

**I am using MAC.**

I am new to azure fabric service. I have already created my local cluster using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-mac .

Now I have to deploy my two Nodejs application on my local cluster. Both applications are running locally. I am unable to connect these applications to my cluster. how can I deploy Nodejs application on azure service fabric cluster using MAC?

Comment: Deploy as guest application e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps

Comment: Or a container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-container-linux